# Javafx center image in imageview with background loading

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview

I want to center an Image in an ImageView. The ImageViews are used for Thumbnails of pictures in a list and I used a fixed Viewport with width and height of 90 to make it look more clean.
The images use BackgroundLoading, so I dont know the dimensions of the Image at the moment of putting it into the ImageView. And of course I dont want to stretch (or crop) the Images. I am using preserveRatio while loading the image.
Is there some way of fitting the image centered into the ImageView, instead of the top left? The longest side of the Images is always 90.

Comment: I solved it by putting the imageView into a  VBox with an empty Pane above and below, widht a minHeight of 0 and a Prefheight of 45 (I chose 45 because it is half the maxheight but you could probably use any number you like). Here is the code:

Answer (score 0):

Since the code was too long for the comment, here it is:

```
    Image image = new Image(pictureURL, 90, 90, true, true, true)

    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(image);        
    VBox imageSpacingVBox = new VBox();

    Pane spaceAbove = new Pane();
    spaceAbove.setMinHeight(0);
    spaceAbove.setPrefHeight(45);

    Pane spaceBelow = new Pane();
    spaceBelow.setMinHeight(0);
    spaceBelow.setPrefHeight(45);

    imageSpacingVBox.setMaxHeight(90);
    imageSpacingVBox.setPrefHeight(90);
    imageSpacingVBox.setMinHeight(90);

    imageSpacingVBox.setMaxWidth(90);
    imageSpacingVBox.setPrefWidth(90);
    imageSpacingVBox.setMinWidth(90);

    imageSpacingVBox.getChildren().addAll(spaceAbove, imgView, spaceBelow);
```

If anyone has an easyer, more elegant solution, I would love to hear about it.